# re loggin using third party( google, FB,Twitter)

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-signin

This is my first major android application, so sorry if this was asked before, but cant seem to find something relevant to help me.

I am developing an android app, where i have managed to add the google sign in method, using the google's guide. My problem now is how to enable my app, to read the users loggin information after they terminate it and relaunch it. Based on some posts here and other guides (which i cant recall now) what i did was storing a boolean variable in SharedPreferences where it states whether the user is logged in or not. `boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(GoogleLogged, false);`
I am loading the SharedPreferences file on the splash screen and make the choice of displaying the login layout or not. other than that I dont save anything else from the login process. I guess that I need to store a token, taken from the google servers, but cant find any relevant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the social login using Twitter,Fb and Google.While logging through all of these you will get different user ids as the user id for the same user for google,Fb and twitter will be different ,if you want create a user id for your users and want to use that for further communications.Get the user details from these apis like name,email and respective user id and the method of login which social medium they used for login and respective to that create a web service which will provide the user id for your usercase and store that userid in shared preferences.So in the splash screen you can check that user has logged in or not.

Comment: ok, so, in addition to the loggin procedure, as described at the google docs, i need to call and save the user's credentials. makes sense. BUT, i think that google doesn’t allow username/password authentication no more. Isn’t that right? also, i have read that user credentials should not be stored in shared prefenreces.

Comment: you may get different user credentials for google,twitter and fb,so how will you handle that

Comment: yes, obviously i would be getting different credentials for each method used, I am just saying that from what i have read shared preferences is not the place to store them.

Comment: yes you shouldn't because there are some methods from where another person can retrieve this token from shared preferences ,what you can do tough use local db to store this or encrypt your shared prefrences there are some external third party libraries also